# Migrate XAMPP databases to LAMP

Tags: xampp, mariadb, lamp

I'd like to migrate databases I have created using XAMPP to the the LAMP stack.

I've installed php, apache and mariadb following this:
[Arch Wiki Apache](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server)

The databases, which are to be imported are not sql-files, but rather ibd and rfm-files located in the /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ directory.

My mariadb datadir is the default /var/lib/mysql.

My question now is how to migrate these ibd and frm files to LAMP correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need the entire tree, not just the .ibd files.

Install the new MySQL first, then copy all the old tree on top.  (Or play games with directory names.)

A potential problem: What version of MySQL are you coming from?  Going to?  There could be incompatibilities.